# How to LIMIT a join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**news** (main  table):

```
+----+-------------------------------+
| id | title                         |
+----+-------------------------------+
|  2 | The title of the story is...  |
+----+-------------------------------+
```

**news_images** (junction table)

```
+---------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| news_id | image_name                           | date                       |
+---------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|       2 | 57a8cab7c09306ca2bbaf02c413aa3d5.jpg | 2015-03-30 16:10:35.743337 |
+---------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|       2 | da98cab7c09306ca2bbaf02c413ab2a9.jpg | 2015-03-30 16:10:30.120232 |
+---------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I want to perform a query that will select all columns from `news` and get the first row from `news_images` that corresponds to the id from `news`.

Initially, my query was:

```
SELECT * FROM news n, news_images ni WHERE n.id = ni.news_id;
```

This SQL query was returning all images from `news_images` table that have the `id` from news. Later, after scanning through Stackoverflow and MySQL docs, I have modified my query to:

```
SELECT n.title, ni.news_image FROM news n, news_images WHERE n.id = ni.news_id AND ni.news_id
    IN (SELECT news_id FROM news_images LIMIT 1);
```

Although, I have the latest MySQL installed, I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 

'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery']
  code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET',
  errno: 1235,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
```

Is there any other way I can limit the join in MySQL? Thank you

Comment: How do you know which is the `first row from news_images` , is there a primary key or timestamp ?

Comment: There is a timestamp, apologies for not mentioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` to also get articles without any images. Use `NOT EXISTS` to find only images where no older image exists for same news_id.

```
SELECT n.title, ni.image, news_images.*
FROM news n LEFT JOIN news_images ni ON n.id = ni.news_id
AND not exists (select 1 from news_images ni2
                where ni.news_id = ni2.news_id
                  and n2i.timestamp < ni.timestamp)
```

Comment: The `left join` is unnecessary.  It can just be a `join`.